# Buffered Loggers (Java)

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm toying around with the idea of building a logging system that pushes log statements to an internal buffer until it reaches a pre-defined capacity, and then dumps (flushes) the whole buffer at once.

This is because I like to sprinkle lots of TRACE statements all throughout my methods (so I can see what's going on every few lines; makes it easier to debug, at least for me). And I'm afraid that with (potentially) hundreds/thousands of log statements firing all over the place that such a large I/O demand will bog my programs down.

A "buffered" logger solution might alleviate this.

Three questions:

1. Does something like this already exist? Hate to reinvent the wheel here, but online searches didn't turn back anything.
2. I was thinking about the fact that I could very well lose log statements whenever the program halts unexpectedly (runtime exceptions, etc.) and the logger hasn't been flushed. In that case I'd like the logger to override finalize() so that if the program terminates with items still in its buffer, it can flush (publish) them prior to exiting. Thoughts?
3. Is this a terrible idea? If so, why!

Comment: Most filesystems already handle buffering, and I suspect (unconfirmed) that file-based loggers already use a buffered writer. `finalize()` may or may not be called if the program goes away. It's not a terrible idea, I'm just not sure it's a good ROI for something that should only be happening during development.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Dave. Question: my thought behind this was that this would be a good tool for any environment, including production. That way I could check production logs to quickly recreate any defects, etc. Can you share your thinking as to why this would only be suitable during development (I'm curious!)? Thanks again

Comment: Because trace and debug log levels are for just that--tracing and debugging, not production. If your system needs that much information in order to track down problems, something else may be wrong. If you *really* believe that much information is necessary, maybe use a JMS logger. Have you *proven* that logging is actually an issue?

Comment: Nope :-) Just my "spidey senses." Thanks for the quick lesson!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't reinvent this particular wheel if you can possibly avoid it. Look at [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html) or better [slf4j](http://slf4j.org/).

Log4j and slf4j are both very performant if you're not tracing, so in the production system you can turn down the level of logging and still have good performance.

Both log4j and slf4j write immediately to the logfiles and flush, don't do buffering by default, for the very good reason that you want to see in the logfile the exception which caused your crash. If you really want to add buffering you can do so ([FileAppender#bufferedIO](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html#bufferedIO))

As far as finalize() is concerned, it is not guaranteed to be called on exit. From [System#runFinalizersOnExit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#runFinalizersOnExit%28boolean%29).

> Deprecated. This method is inherently unsafe. It may result in
>   finalizers being called on live objects while other threads are
>   concurrently manipulating those objects, resulting in erratic behavior
>   or deadlock. Enable or disable finalization on exit; doing so
>   specifies that the finalizers of all objects that have finalizers that
>   have not yet been automatically invoked are to be run before the Java
>   runtime exits. **By default, finalization on exit is disabled**.

My emphasis. So, no it seems like a buffered logger would have inherent problems.

Answer (score 2):

I will attest to the third question you posed.  This is a terrible idea and it has nothing to do with your skill as a programmer.  What it has to do with is the number of scenarios that projects like log4j have been exposed to and the different edge cases that they have accounted for.  I think this undertaking is quite large for you and will cause a lot of headaches down the road.

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to see that. Thanks for the candor!

Answer (score 1):

Log4J already supports IO buffering. Some nice performance tips on Log4J [here](http://fredpuls.com/site/softwaredevelopment/java/log4j/log4j_performance_tips.htm)

Comment: link is broken. Please try to copy/paste relevant content in the future so that it remains even if the site is down. If the information is too large, then yes, a link and hopes for uptime is best :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of existing frameworks, AFAIK none "buffer" in local memory. But check out the standard Log4J etc.

`finalize()` is not the right thing. Use `Runtime.addShutdownHook()`. See [what I learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880569/does-jvm-gc-call-finalize-on-program-thread-exit) recently.

Answer (score 0):

We do a similar thing with our production servers except they are firing the log messages across a network connection.  We just have a bounded linked queue and make decisions about ejecting debug messages and keeping errors if the queue is full.  Then we have a thread in the background firing the messages to the server.

1. I don't know of such a thing as part of log4j or slf4j.
2. The only way you would lose messages is if the JVM crashes in which case a buffer writer would have the same problems.  If you writing thread is not daemon then it can finish writing the log messages when the application is going down before quitting.
3. The only reason it would be a terrible idea is if there really isn't a performance problem with your logging.  It might be good to make sure that you isolate your logging calls to own logging wrapper *in case* you need to queue them up for the future.  But for the short-term just write through to log4j or whatever.   You can also put some statistics in this wrapping class to see if logging messages are holding up the process at all and then making an informed decision to improve it's performance through queueing.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned - don't re-invent the wheel - use log4j or even better logback (its successor), but do it wisely. Default simple appenders which write and flush into disk immediately will impact the overall performance of your app. Normally, appender does hard work on the thread of the caller. To avoid this you either write your own appender which does this asynchronously (with buffering) or use wrappers - depending on the framework you can wrap some appenders with asynchronous behavior without writing single line of code. I have such appender [here](http://www.moonlit-software.com/logfaces/web/download/index.php) (see bottom of the page), you can use the code freely or just get an idea. My appender works against TCP sockets, but the issue is the same - to prevent blocking of the caller and do the flushing on separate thread so that application on top doesn't ever feel it.